# How do I construct an "If loop" inside of a for loop for rows and columns?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have a data frame in R which has measurements of fold change (fc) and columns which are fc_0.1, fc_0.2 etc. until fc_2. I am attempting to populate every row in each column with a 1 if it equals or is greater than the value of the first column based on the specific column name. I originally did this very tediously by specifying every column and now I am trying to shorten the code and generalize it. I have made this for loop does lots of the work, but I am unable to integrate these if statements into the loop. It would be really great I did not have to write an if statement for every 0.1 increment.

```
fc <- c(0.82,0.03,1.52,0.14,0.61,1.88,0.29,1.91,0.32,0.46,1.76,0.54,1.45,2.01,0.71,1.45,0.90,1.01,1.17,1.68,1.21,1.37)
data<- data.frame(abs(fc)) # create a data frame fold change
z<- data.frame(rep.int(0, 22))
z[2:20] <- z[[1]] # create a data frame of zeros
data <- data.frame(data,z) # add the two data frames together
names(data) <- c("fc",paste0("fc_", seq(0.1, 2, by = 0.1))) # give names to the columns
data

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  for(j in 2:ncol(data)){
     if(data[i,1]>=0.1){
    data[i,2]=1
     }
    if(data[i,1]>=0.2){
    data[i,3]=1
    }
    if(data[i,1]>=0.3){
    data[i,4]=1
    }
    if(data[i,1]>=0.4){
    data[i,5]=1
    }
    if(data[i,1]>=0.5){
    data[i,6]=1
    }
    if(data[i,1]>=0.6){
    data[i,7]=1
    }
    if(data[i,1]>=0.7){
    data[i,8]=1
    }
    if(data[i,1]>=0.8){
    data[i,9]=1
    }
    if(data[i,1]>=0.9){
    data[i,10]=1
    }
    if(data[i,1]>=1.0){
    data[i,11]=1 
    } 
   } 
  }
data
```

I would have to write an if statement for all the 0.1 increments if I wanted to get all of the columns populated. This makes the code very long and will not be scaleable if I increase the amount of values needed.

I have tried a 3rd for loop to try and integrate the numbers calculated by the if statements for every column.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  for(j in 2:ncol(data)){
    for(k in seq(0.1, 2, by = 0.1)){
           if(data[i,1]>=k){
    data[i,j]=1
     }
    }
   } 
  }
```

This populates 1s in every row and column regardless of the value of the first column (except for 0.03 which is mysteriously still populated with 0s). I cannot figure out a way to make my code easier, but I know it can be done somehow. Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemingly obscure, this is much more idiomatic R:

```r
data[,-1] <- (+outer(data[[1]], as.numeric(sub("fc_", "", names(data)[-1])), `<`))
data
#      fc fc_0.1 fc_0.2 fc_0.3 fc_0.4 fc_0.5 fc_0.6 fc_0.7 fc_0.8 fc_0.9 fc_1 fc_1.1 fc_1.2 fc_1.3 fc_1.4 fc_1.5 fc_1.6 fc_1.7 fc_1.8 fc_1.9 fc_2
# 1  0.82      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 2  0.03      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 3  1.52      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1    1
# 4  0.14      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 5  0.61      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 6  1.88      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1    1
# 7  0.29      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 8  1.91      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    1
# 9  0.32      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 10 0.46      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 11 1.76      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1    1
# 12 0.54      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 13 1.45      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 14 2.01      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0
# 15 0.71      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 16 1.45      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 17 0.90      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 18 1.01      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 19 1.17      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 20 1.68      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1    1
# 21 1.21      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
# 22 1.37      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
```

Walk-through:

- `as.numeric(sub(..))` is merely extracting and number-ifying the column names, results in `c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, ..., 2)`.
- `data[[1]]` could be `data$fc` or whatever, it just returns the actual `fc` numbers you need
- `` outer(val1, val2, `<`) `` does an outer calculation of all values in `val1` with all values in `val2`. It returns a matrix of dimensions `length(val1)`x`length(val2)`:

  ```r
  outer(data[[1]], as.numeric(sub("fc_", "", names(data)[-1])), `<`)
  #        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
  #  [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  #  [2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  #  [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  #  [4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  #  [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  #  [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
  #  [7,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  #  [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  #  [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [11,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [12,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [13,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [14,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  # [15,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [16,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [17,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [18,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [19,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [20,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [21,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [22,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  ```
- since we really want `1`s and `0`s, we wrap that in `+(..)` for R's implicit cast from logical to integer:

  ```r
  +(outer(data[[1]], as.numeric(sub("fc_", "", names(data)[-1])), `<`))
  #       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
  #  [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  #  [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  #  [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
  #  [4,]    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  #  [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  #  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
  #  [7,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  #  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
  #  [9,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  # [10,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  # [11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
  # [12,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  # [13,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
  # [14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  # [15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  # [16,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
  # [17,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  # [18,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  # [19,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  # [20,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
  # [21,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  # [22,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  ```
- we then reassign that back into the frame (all except column 1) with `data[,-1] <- ...`.

Some thoughts: in R, it is generally much faster to work with things as whole vectors instead of element-wise. For instance,

```r
1:10 < 5
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

does ten comparisons, but the expression is (at least in my head) much simpler and easy to understand. This logic can be extended into matrices and such (though I don't use that here). We *do* use that `` `<` `` operation implicitly in our call to `outer`. Internally, `outer` produces two much longer vectors. For a much smaller example,

```r
vec1 <- 1:3
vec2 <- 11:14
outer(vec1, vec2, function(a, b) { browser(); a + b; })
# Browse[2]>
a
#  [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
# Browse[2]>
b
#  [1] 11 11 11 12 12 12 13 13 13 14 14 14
```

Notice that it expanded `vec1` to be the length of `length(vec1)*length(vec2)`, with `vec1` being repeated as a whole `length(vec2)` times; and it repeated `vec2` by `length(vec1)` times for each value, changing values more slowly.

With that, and `a` (the first argument to our anon-function) and `b` both the same lengths, it then simply `a + b`, which is a piece-wise addition of the two vectors.

```r
# Browse[2]> 
a + b
#  [1] 12 13 14 13 14 15 14 15 16 15 16 17
```

This output is then re-dimensioned by `outer` so that it is in the proper matrix as expected from `outer`. (Sometimes this matrix is not necessary, but it is trivial to un-matricize it with `c(outer(..))` then it is to re-dimension to the lengths of the original args.

```r
# Browse[2]>
c                             # <--- continues out of the debugger
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   12   13   14   15
# [2,]   13   14   15   16
# [3,]   14   15   16   17
```

---

Data

```r
data <- structure(list(fc = c(0.82, 0.03, 1.52, 0.14, 0.61, 1.88, 0.29, 1.91, 0.32, 0.46, 1.76, 0.54, 1.45, 2.01, 0.71, 1.45, 0.9, 1.01, 1.17, 1.68, 1.21, 1.37), fc_0.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_0.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_0.3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_0.4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_0.5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_0.6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_0.7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_0.8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_0.9 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_1.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0), fc_1.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_1.3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_1.4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_1.5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_1.6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_1.7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_1.8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_1.9 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fc_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short, (I think) readable dplyr approach using `across`. This says we want to 1) take `data`, then 2) change all the columns except `fc` 3) to be a number version of the test (eg 1 for TRUE, 0 for FALSE) comparing the parsed value of the current column name to the value in `fc`.

```
library(dplyr)
data |>
  mutate(across(-fc, ~1*(parse_number(cur_column()) > fc)))
```

Result

```
     fc fc_0.1 fc_0.2 fc_0.3 fc_0.4 fc_0.5 fc_0.6 fc_0.7 fc_0.8 fc_0.9 fc_1 fc_1.1 fc_1.2 fc_1.3 fc_1.4 fc_1.5 fc_1.6 fc_1.7 fc_1.8 fc_1.9 fc_2
1  0.82      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
2  0.03      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
3  1.52      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1    1
4  0.14      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
5  0.61      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
6  1.88      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1    1
7  0.29      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
8  1.91      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    1
9  0.32      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
10 0.46      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
11 1.76      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1    1
12 0.54      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
13 1.45      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1    1
14 2.01      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0
15 0.71      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
16 1.45      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1    1
17 0.90      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
18 1.01      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
19 1.17      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
20 1.68      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1    1
21 1.21      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
22 1.37      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1    1
```

---

Here's a tidyverse approach using reshaping. Number the rows, reshape longer, compare the `fc` value to the number in the column name, and reshape wide again:

```
library(tidyverse)
data |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |> # not necessary if `fc` values guaranteed unique
  pivot_longer(-c(row, fc)) |>
  mutate(value = 1 * (parse_number(name) > fc)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)


# A tibble: 22 × 22
      fc   row fc_0.1 fc_0.2 fc_0.3 fc_0.4 fc_0.5 fc_0.6 fc_0.7 fc_0.8 fc_0.9  fc_1 fc_1.1 fc_1.2 fc_1.3 fc_1.4 fc_1.5 fc_1.6 fc_1.7 fc_1.8 fc_1.9  fc_2
   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1  0.82     1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1     1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     1
 2  0.03     2      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     1
 3  1.52     3      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1     1
 4  0.14     4      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     1
 5  0.61     5      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1     1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     1
 6  1.88     6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1     1
 7  0.29     7      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     1
 8  1.91     8      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     1
 9  0.32     9      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1     1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     1
10  0.46    10      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1     1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     1
# ℹ 12 more rows
```